# Encountered a heap-buffer-overflow while itterating with pointers

Tags: c++, buffer-overflow

I have a program with the aim of finding the GCD of two strings `s` and `t`, i.e, return the largest `x` such that `x|s` and `x|t`. While testing this program, I encountered a `heap-buffer-overflow`. I am aware that this error implies a segmentation fault. However, I am not sure where in the program this error arises.

```
string gcdOfStrings(string str1, string str2) {

        const char *ptrI = str1.c_str(), *ptrJ = str2.c_str();
        char *str3 = new char[1000 + 1], *ptrK = str3;
        bool boolI = false, boolJ = false;

        while (*ptrI == *ptrJ) { *ptrK++ = *ptrI++; }

        ptrI = str1.c_str();

        while ( (*ptrI != '\0') || (*ptrJ != '\0') || (*ptrK != '\0') ) {

            if (*ptrK == '\0') { ptrK = str3; }
            
            if (*ptrI != *ptrK) { boolI = true; }
            if (*ptrI != '\0')  { ptrI++; }

            if (*ptrJ != *ptrK) { boolJ = true; }
            if (*ptrJ != '\0')  { ptrJ++; }

            if ( (boolI != true) && (boolJ != true) ) { *ptrK = '\0'; string t(str3); delete[] str3; return t; }

            ptrK++;
        }
        
        return "";
    }
```

**Example 1:**

Input: str1 = "ABCABC", str2 = "ABC"
Output: "ABC"

**Example 2:**

Input: str1 = "ABABAB", str2 = "ABAB"
Output: "AB"

**Example 3:**

Input: str1 = "ABABCB", str2 = "ABAB"
Output: ""

Comment: `while (*ptrI == *ptrJ) { *ptrK++ = *ptrI++; }` ... this may run out of bounds since it's not checking for `'\0'`. Think about two empty strings for example.

Comment: A debugger will tell you immediately where in the program this error arises.

Comment: You'll be glad to hear that you don't need anyone's help to figure this out, just a tool you already have: your debugger! This is exactly what a debugger is for: it runs your program, one line at a time, and [shows you what's happening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/)!! This is something that's every C++ developer must know how to do. With your debugger's help you'll able to quickly find all problems in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help. Have you tried using your debugger, already? If not, why not? What did your debugger show you?'

Comment: I am on LeetCode, and the platform's debugger is locked unless I set up a payment plan.

Comment: Then run it at your own computer where you can install all the debuggers you need.  g++ and clang++ also supports some sanitizer options that you can use. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/rWajEEx46)

Comment: The contents of `str3` is uninitialised, i think your code is assuming it's filled with `\0`?

Comment: "I am on LeetCode, and the platform's debugger is locked " - if you aren't learning to use a debugger, you aren't learning to become a developer.  It's a required skill for a professional.

Comment: What is this magic number `1000 + 1`? (And why manual memory allocation instead of using another `std::string`?)

Comment: The question really should either indicate where the error occurs or the input that causes the error, preferably both. As it is, I see three errors in your code, and I do not know which (if any -- there could be other errors) is the cause of the crash you are investigating.

Comment: *I am on LeetCode, and the platform's debugger is locked unless I set up a payment plan* -- Interesting -- if this is true, then anyone paying money for debugger usage is being cheated out of their money.   All you have to do is install a compiler, take the code you have now, write a small `main` program with the test data, and debug the program using the debugger that comes with the compiler.  Now I wonder if all of these other Leetcode questions that stackoverflow gets that have no debugging effort is because of the (assumed) extortion tactics that leetcode uses...