# Runtime error when running QuickSort using while loops in split function

Tags: c++, quicksort

I implemented my QuickSort algorithm as follows. The sortArray function the entry point for sorting the array. It initializes the lower and upper bounds of the array and then calls the quicksort function. The quicksort recursively sorts the array by dividing it into smaller subarrays and sorting each subarray. It calls the split function to partition the array. The split function returns the index of the where the split has to be made. The code is as follows -

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> sortArray(vector<int>& nums) {
        
        cout << "Running Code" << endl;
        int lower = 0;
        int upper = nums.size() - 1;
        

        quicksort(lower, upper, nums);
        return nums;
    }

    void quicksort(int lower, int upper, vector <int> &nums )
    {
        if(lower<upper)
        {
            int index = split(lower, upper, nums);
            cout << index << endl;
            quicksort(lower,index-1,nums);
            quicksort(index+1,upper,nums);
        }
        
    }

    int split(int lower, int upper, vector<int> &nums)
    {
        int base = nums[lower];
        int start = lower;
        int end = upper;

        printf("start: %d end: %d\n", start, end);
        
        while(start < end)
        {
                      
            while(nums[start] < base);
            start++;
          
            while(nums[end] > base);
            end--;

            if(start<end)
            swap(nums[start], nums[end]);

        }

        swap(nums[lower],nums[end]);

        return end;

       


    }
};
```

I want to recursively sort the array, but I get a runtime error as shown below-

```
=================================================================
==22==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x5020000000a0 at pc 0x558a0c57ac59 bp 0x7ffcb3489590 sp 0x7ffcb3489588
READ of size 4 at 0x5020000000a0 thread T0
    #4 0x7fa09395ed8f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29d8f) (BuildId: c289da5071a3399de893d2af81d6a30c62646e1e)
    #5 0x7fa09395ee3f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29e3f) (BuildId: c289da5071a3399de893d2af81d6a30c62646e1e)
0x5020000000a0 is located 0 bytes after 16-byte region [0x502000000090,0x5020000000a0)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #6 0x7fa09395ed8f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29d8f) (BuildId: c289da5071a3399de893d2af81d6a30c62646e1e)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x501ffffffe00: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x501ffffffe80: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x501fffffff00: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x501fffffff80: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x502000000000: fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa
=>0x502000000080: fa fa 00 00[fa]fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x502000000100: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x502000000180: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x502000000200: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x502000000280: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x502000000300: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
==22==ABORTING
```

I spent a lot of time trying to debug the code but with no luck. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Recommendation: Turn on address Sanitizer and debugging information in your build. If you rebuild the program and feed in the same set of test inputs, you will get a much more complete diagnostic that tells you pretty much exactly what went wrong and where. This leaves only fixing the problem up to you.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to implement [Hoare partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme). Compare the implementation at the link to what you've written. The mistake will likely be in the differences between the two.

Comment: _Please_ use `std::swap` instead of implementing swaps manually. You're doing this in one place already. Do it in the other place, too.

Comment: If you don't have an input set that triggers the failure, test against `vector<int> nums{3,1,2,4,7};`. It doesn't trigger the buffer overflow, but it does go into an infinite (or at least stupidly long) loop. Fixing one may fix the other, and if not, you have one fewer bugs to fix. Debuggers eat infinite loops for breakfast. Run the program in the debugger, wait for it to lock up, pause the program and see where it is, Step through a couple iterations of the accidental loop to see why and how it happens. Then fix.

Comment: @user4581301 - I was using Leetcode and I dont have the premium version to debug the code :( But thanks for the tip.

Comment: <Expletive deleted> Leetcode. Don't waste your time debugging via judge. They don't provide enough information BY DESIGN. Set up a build system on a computer under your control. You'll get MUCH better tool support. With a decent debugger at your fingertips you should be able to isolate the problem in under five minutes.

Comment: @blazingcannon -- *and I dont have the premium version to debug the code* -- Please [read this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78057747/encountered-a-heap-buffer-overflow-while-itterating-with-pointers#comment137611678_78057747) concerning having to pay "premium" to use a debugger.  You are getting swindled if leetcode is charging money for debugger usage.

Comment: *I implemented my QuickSort algorithm as follows.* -- [How to implement classic sorting algorithms using modern C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650626/how-to-implement-classic-sorting-algorithms-in-modern-c).  Look at the QuickSort there and learn how it accomplishes the job.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I didn't read blazingcannon's comment well enough to realize he-or-she was talking about a paid version with a debugger. Holy <expletive deleted>! What a racket! That's a bigger screwjob than I thought they offered.

Comment: Blazingcannon, perfectly usable development tools have been free (in varying meanings of free) for decades. Under many circumstances I prefer the open-source-free tools because they don't have the same motivation to force you into [a vendor lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vendor_lock-in).

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues:

- `while(nums[start] < base);` is a loop with an empty body (notice the semicolon), so if the condition is true, the loop will never exit. You have the same error in the next `while` loop.
- In your partitioning implementation, you're mixing concepts from [the Lomuto scheme and the Hoare scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme). Here are some key differences (of `split`) between the two schemes:

  | Property | Lomuto | Hoare | Your code's *intent* |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  | Is the returned index always the pivot's index? | yes | no | yes |
  | Is the original pivot index excluded from the loop? | yes | no | no |
  | Does the loop have two indices that walk *towards* eachother? | no | yes | yes |

  As you can see the *intent* of your code (ignoring the bugs) does not match with either scheme.

As Hoare's scheme performs significantly fewer swaps on average, I suggest you fix your code to align with that scheme:

- As Hoare's scheme does not necessarily return the index of the pivot, and the pivot value could be anywhere at either side, the first recursive call of `quicksort` should not exclude that index. So change it to:

  ```
  quicksort(lower,index,nums);
  ```
- The final swap in `split` is not a step of Hoare's scheme, and it would not work either: the pivot value at `lower` might have been swapped to a different location, so it would bring havoc in that case. You should omit this `swap`.
- To avoid more complex code, an implementation of Hoare's algorithm will actually always increment `start` and decrement `end` at least once per iteration of the loop. So change your inner `while` loops to `do...while` loops.

Here is the correction of your quicksort code, using Hoare's scheme:

```
    void quicksort(int lower, int upper, vector <int> &nums )
    {
        if(lower<upper)
        {
            int index = split(lower, upper, nums);
            quicksort(lower,index,nums); // Hoare's scheme cannot exclude index
            quicksort(index+1,upper,nums); 
        }
    }

    int split(int lower, int upper, vector<int> &nums)
    {
        int base = nums[lower];
        int start = lower - 1;  // Start one off
        int end = upper + 1;    // (idem)

        while(start < end)
        {
            do { // Always increment at least once
                start++;
            }
            while(nums[start] < base); 
          
            do { // Always decrement at least once
                end--;
            }
            while(nums[end] > base);

            if(start<end)
                swap(nums[start], nums[end]);
        }
        // Hoare's scheme does not attempt to swap the pivot value to nums[end] 
        return end;
    }
```